# jQuery Plugin Syntax/ JavaScript Syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this syntaxt many times, in JavaScript or jQuery Plugin

```
$.fn.testPlugin = function( options ) {  

    // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
    var settings = $.extend( {
      'location'         : 'top',
      'background-color' : 'blue'
    }, options);
```

I do understand that the function is extended but what after `$.extend({})` is not clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

The [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method will merge any key/value pairs given in objects in the the second (and subsequent) parameter into the object passed in the first parameter.  It then returns the (updated) first parameter as its result.

Hence this is just a way of specifying some default values for those two options, which will be overridden by any that the plugin user passes in the `options` parameter to the plugin.

For example, if you called:

```
$(el).testPlugin({ location: 'left' });
```

then within the plugin the resulting settings will be:

```
var settings = {
    location:         'left',
    background-color: 'blue'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.extend() is syntax for merging the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/